# Getting Ruby to chdir to remote server on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, directory, chdir

I am stuck with changing a directory to "\10.10.10.10\D$\some_dir"

```
FileUtils.chdir("\\\\10.10.10.10\\D$\\some_dir\\")
```

and

```
Dir.chdir("\\\\10.10.10.10\\D$\\some_dir\\")
```

do not work in Ruby 1.9.3! It worked in Ruby 1.8.7

Any ideas how to change dir to a remote box dir?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Works for me. What happens when you follow with `puts Dir.pwd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK that was a problem in windows, it could not access the specified folder on remote box because the credentials were not specified for accessing that folder,  all i haqve done is go to win explorer and in address line put the path to that folder on remote box "\10.10.10.10\D$\some_dir"   - the credentials is prompted after that , just enter them and put "remember credentials" after you access the folder via explorer the script runs ok